# Is it possible to add a method to a Python list instance?

Tags: python, list, monkeypatching

I'm trying to "monkey patch" an *instance* of list. Mind you, it isn't *my* list. I have no control over its creation. As far as I can see, this is not possible in 2.7. Am I right? Is it possible in 3.x?

Answer (score 6):

No, you can't add or remove attributes on a `list` object, not in Python 2 and not in Python 3.

At best you can wrap such an object in another instance, one that implements the same attributes and methods as a list but passes on access to those to the wrapped listobject.

That wrapper could be implemented with the [`UserList.UserList()` class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/userdict.html#module-UserList):

```
try:
    # Python 2
    from UserList import UserList
except ImportError:
    # Python 3
    from collections import UserList

class ListWrapper(UserList):
    def extra_method(self):
        return """Hi! I'm an extra method on this "list" (wink, wink)"""
```

Demo:

```
>>> some_list = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
>>> wrapped_list = ListWrapper(some_list)
>>> len(wrapped_list)
3
>>> wrapped_list[1]
'bar'
>>> wrapped_list.extra_method()
'Hi! I\'m an extra method on this "list" (wink, wink)'
```

Comment: Learn something new everyday :)

Comment: What's the advantage of using `UserList` over `list` in python 3?

Comment: @Dunes: If you subclass `list`, any method or operator that returns a new instance (such as concatenation) returns a regular `list` object again, while a `UserList` subclass will always return the wrapper class instead.

Comment: I learn something new everyday. This will be useful for some code of mine.

Comment: I thought it might be something like that. I tried it out for myself in python 3.4 and it didn't work. I sliced a subclass of `UserList` and got a `list` instance.

Comment: @Dunes: ah, yes, the `__getitem__` method delegates straight to `self.data.__getitem__`. That's easily fixed, but still, that's unexpected given that `__add__` and `__mul__` return an instance of the class.

Comment: @Dunes: in Python 2, it works provided you don't use a stride (e.g. extended slice notation), because the `__getslice__` method is used. But Python 3 removed that altogether (since `__getitem__` was enough to handle all slicing with the `slice()` object). This is a bit of a bug, really.

Comment: It should be noted that UserList doesn't really "wrap" the provided list; it makes a copy.

Comment: @user2357112: yes, just like `list(listobj)` makes a copy. You could override the `__init__` if you want it to be a full proxy; `def __init__(self, data): self.data = data` is enough.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a lightweight way to add a single method to a single  instance of a subclass of `list`

```
>>> import new
>>> L = ['f', 'o', 'o']
>>> M = type("list", (list, ), {})(L)
>>> M.bar = new.instancemethod(lambda self: self * 2, M)
>>> M.bar()
['f', 'o', 'o', 'f', 'o', 'o']
```

Comment: `M + ['foo']` returns a regular `list` object.